# Getting readiness probe failed: dial tcp <IP>:5672 connect: connection refused error in rabbitmq-cluster pods

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift, readinessprobe

I am new to rabbitmq and would appreciate help in the issue I am facing.

I have deployed rabbitmq using the rabbitmq cluster k8s operator on openshift which is hosted on Azure. ([This is the guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/quickstart-operator.html) I referred to deploy the operator).

The operator and cluster is up and running, also able to access the management UI on localhost:15672.

But when I describe the pod, it shows the warning of readiness probe failed:

> dial tcp <IP>:5672 connect: connection refused

Due to this, when I try to run the rabbitmq [hello world tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html), it fails with the error:

```
connect ETIMEDOUT 172.30.69.51:5672
errno: -4039
code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
syscall:'connect'
address: 172.30.69.51
port:5672
```

(172.30.69.51 is the clusterIP)

From the management UI, I am able to create new exchange, queue and binding and send & publish msgs.

PS. apologies if the conversation format is incorrect, pls feel free to correct me and I'll take care from next time. Thank you.

Comment: ```

    dial tcp <IP>:5672 connect: connection refused
``` that probably means that the service isn't fully ready yet. can you add the pod logs via `oc logs <podname> -n <namespace>` ?

Comment: Hi Rick, In the pod logs I am just getting the output as > Closing all channels from connection <random IP>:<random port> -> <pod IP>:5672 because it has been closed

Comment: Did you find the reason of this behavior?